# How to add a prefix to a php recordset variable

Tags: php

Iam deleting a record from the database and trying to delete the associated images, the main full size image and the thumbnail. I can delete the database entry and the big image but don't know how to add a prefix to the thumbnail delete part. I want it to be "th" before the second FILE_NAME so it deletes the thumbnail image as well.  Please see code below:

```
chdir('../gallery/');
$do = unlink($row_Recordset1['FILE_NAME']);
$do = unlink($row_Recordset1['FILE_NAME']);
if($do=="1"){
header(sprintf("Location: cpanel.php"));
} else { echo "There was an error trying to delete the file."; }
```

Comment: `I want it to be "th" before the second FILE_NAME so it deletes the thumbnail image as well.` my brain just melted

Comment: I would probably not bother with `chdir()` here... Add that into the path sent to `unlink()`.  As in `unlink('../gallery/th' . $row_Recordset1['FILE_NAME']);`  There isn't a need to switch the working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.` concatenation operator.

```
$do = unlink('th' . $row_Recordset1['FILE_NAME']);
```